# Why use an AtomicU32 in Rust, given that U32 already implements Sync?

Tags: multithreading, types, rust, thread-safety, atomic

The `std::sync::atomic` module contains a number of atomic variants of primitive types, with the stated purpose that these types are now thread-safe. However, all the primatives that correspond to the atomic types already implement `Send` and `Sync`, and should therefore already be thread-safe. What's the reasoning behind the `Atomic` types?

Comment: In short: `Sync` is about immutable sharing, `Atomic` (and `*Cell`) - about shared mutability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, non-atomic integers are safe to share across threads because they're immutable.  If you attempt to modify the value, you implicitly create a new one in most cases because they're `Copy`.  However, it isn't safe to share a mutable *reference* to a `u32` across threads (or have both mutable and immutable references to the same value), which practically means that you won't be able to modify the variable and have another thread see the results.  An atomic type has some additional behavior which makes it safe.

In the more general case, using non-atomic operations doesn't guarantee that a change made in one thread will be visible in another.  Many architectures, especially RISC architectures, do not guarantee that behavior without additional instructions.

In addition, compilers often reorder accesses to memory in functions and in some cases, across functions, and an atomic type with an appropriate barrier is required to indicate to the compiler that such behavior is not wanted.

Finally, atomic operations are often required to logically update the contents of a variable.  For example, I may want to atomically add 1 to a variable.  On a load-store architecture such as ARM, I cannot modify the contents of memory with an add instruction; I can only perform arithmetic on registers.  Consequently, an atomic add is multiple instructions, usually consisting of a load-linked, which loads a memory location, the add operation on the register, and then a store-conditional, which stores the value if the memory location has not changed.  There's also a loop to retry if it has.

These are why atomic operations are needed and generally useful across languages.  So while one *can* use non-atomic operations in non-Rust languages, they don't generally produce useful results, and since one typically wants one's code to function correctly, atomic operations are desirable for correctness.  Rust's atomic types guarantee this behavior by generating suitable instructions and therefore can be safely shared across threads.

Comment: You should mention that `AtomicU32` provides methods for mutating the value through a shared reference, whereas `u32` doesn't. Also, "An atomic type is actually a pointer" is false; `AtomicU32` is not a pointer. What makes `AtomicU32` unusual is that it allows you to mutate the value through a shared reference. Finally, "Generally, non-atomic integers are safe to share across threads because they're `Copy`.": the fact that a type is `Copy` or not has nothing to do with thread-safety. `u32` is thread-safe because it's immutable while it's shared.